# Catch the browser closing event in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I want an event that work when I close browser only (not close tab or reload page).

I am using the following code :

```
$(window).on("unload",function(){
    localStorage.clear();
});
```

I have tried `onunload` & `onbeforeunload`, it works for **close browser, reload page, close tabs**, but for me I want an event that **affects only close browser**. Any recommended event (close browser only) for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/detect-browser-or-tab-closing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect browser or tab closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/detect-browser-or-tab-closing)

Comment: both `onunload` & `onbeforeunload` is the same, but my case is i want event only **close browser**

Comment: `onunload` & `onbeforeunload` work for close browser, reload page, close tabs, but for me i want which event effect only close broswer

Answer (score 0):

You can only detect an unload of a page, not closing of the browser. It just cannot be done.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such event that exclusively works on browser close.